# Python matrix provide with numpy.dot()

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix-multiplication

During my acquaintance with CUDA in Python (numba lib), I implemented matrix provide methods:

- Just with `numpy.dot()`
- Strassen algorithm with `numpy.dot()`
- Blocks method on GPU
- Strassen algorithm on GPU

So I tested it on 2 types of data:

- `numpy.random.randint(0, 5, (N, N)) # with int32 elements`
- `numpy.random.random((N, N))        # with float64 elements`

For int32 i obtained expected result, where my GPU algroithms performed better than CPU with numpy:
[image]

However, on float64 type, `numpy.dot()` outperformed all my GPU methods:
[image]

So, question is:
**Why is `numpy.dot()` so fast with `float64` arrays, and does numpy use the GPU?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A typical installation of numpy will be dynamically linked against a [BLAS library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms), which provides routines for matrix-matrix and matrix-vector multiplication. For example, when you use `np.dot()` on a pair of float64 arrays, numpy will call the BLAS [`dgemm` routine](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d2b/dgemm_8f.html) in the background. Although these library functions run on the CPU rather than the GPU, they are often multithreaded, and are very finely tuned for performance. A good BLAS implementation, such as [MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl) or [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/), will probably be hard to beat in terms of performance, even on the GPU*.

However, BLAS only supports floating point types. If you call `np.dot()` on integer arrays, numpy will fall back on using [a very simple internal C++ implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/8b44a5522628cae522f00985b4ac7b3f6c21fb18/numpy/core/src/multiarray/arraytypes.c.src#L3228-L3253), which is single-threaded and much slower than a BLAS dot on two floating point arrays.

Without knowing more about how you conducted those benchmarks, I would bet that a plain call to `numpy.dot` would also comfortably beat your other 3 methods for float32, complex64 and complex128 arrays, which are the other 3 types supported by BLAS.

---

* One possible way to beat standard BLAS would be to use [cuBLAS](http://scikits.appspot.com/cuda), which is a BLAS implementation that will run on an NVIDIA GPU. The [`scikit-cuda`](http://scikits.appspot.com/cuda) library seems to provide Python bindings for it, although I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that numpy will automatically use multiple cpu processors where it has the libraries compiled. For some functions (and I think dot() was one of the ones, though I can't find ref now). I suspect this is what's happening. I'm not aware of any attempts to get a numpy gpu back end http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1mw9mb/is_there_a_gpu_backend_for_numpyscipy_money_is_no/